# what is `top` referring to as virtual memory on a swapless machine

Tags: linux, performance, memory, command-line

I'm trying to assess the performance of a set of python scripts on a swap-less machine.

Monitoring the process with the `top` command gives a virtual memory size slightly bigger than the resident memory size.

At this point, what does virtual memory refer to? Does it include the resident memory?

edit: removed python tag as per comments on it not being relevant

Comment: I don't think Python is relevant here in any way.

Comment: I suppose is "memory pagination" related

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/138427/top-what-does-virtual-memory-size-mean-linux-ubuntu (note the part about memory mapping files)

Comment: thanks to Jon Clements, answer found at

http://serverfault.com/questions/138427/top-what-does-virtual-memory-size-mean-linux-ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two points, why it makes sense for top to list virtual memory usage in this case:

1. As kindall noted, there are memory maps. With the effect, that not everything that is mapped into memory actually has to reside in it. It also has the effect, that frequently used files like shared libraries only have to be loaded into memory once, they are simply mapped into the virtual address spaces of several processes.
2. When you ask Linux for some mem, it just takes a note, that you have it in your virtual address space without actually providing it. That means, you are free to ask for much more memory than can possibly be provided, blowing up the figure reported by top as the virtual memory allocated to you. You just cannot use all of that memory, because the OOM-killer will simply shoot you when the kernel runs out of memory.

Both points make it very clear that you are still working under a fully virtualized memory system, that just cannot do the other trick of swapping arbitrary pages out to disk for a "gracefull" degradation.

Comment: Thanks for a clear and concise answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not a programming question, but wotthehell. The executables and their shared libraries are memory-mapped into RAM rather than being loaded all at once when the executable starts. This reduces process startup time and can also reduce real memory use (if not all the code in the executable is needed for whatever you're doing with it). This isn't swap, but it's done by the VM system and so counts as virtual memory.

Comment: true, in retrospect I should have posted to http://unix.stackexchange.com/